# Are clGetEventProfilingInfo() time stamps synchronized?

Tags: opencl, performance-testing, multi-gpu

I am trying to profile code in a multi GPU environment with `clGetEventProfilingInfo()` but it looks to me that I cannot correlate the time stamps from different GPUs. A simple [code sample](https://github.com/matze/mgpu) is twice as fast using two GPUs than using one, but the time stamps suggest that one GPU executed most of the work before the other even started.

The [spec] http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventProfilingInfo.html) just says, that such a time stamp is *"A 64-bit value that describes the current device time counter in nanoseconds [...]"*.

Do I have to assume that these don't have to be synchronized?

---

FYI:

- I am using two NVIDIA GTX 580 with NVIDIA driver version 295.40, Linux kernel 2.6.35
- I already asked this question over at the [Khronos forums](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=5250) but did not receive a reply yet.

Comment: How to synchronize them ?

Answer (score 0):

The spec also says *"OpenCL devices are required to correctly track time across changes in device frequency and power states."*  It would imply that the returned times differ only by a constant between two devices, and between each device and the "real" wall clock time.

Comment: To me this part implies that if a device changes its frequency or state it should still be able to correctly track time, regardless of other devices.